# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3, 1509]

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, linear-regression, training-data

I'm trying to pass y_train and u_train data to sklearn's LinearRegression.fit() function as follows:

```
LinearRegression.fit(u_train, y_train)
```

Both u_train and y_train have sizes of (503,3) (see below)

[image]

I don't understand why I am getting a dimension mismatch error since u_train and y_train are the same size. I get the error "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3, 1509]." Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: We cannot help you with so little information, you need to include a reproducible code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that you're invoking the class rather than an instance. Usage should be like:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

#Make new instance
linear_reg = LinearRegression()
#Fit
linear_reg.fit(u_train, y_train)

#One-liner alternative
linear_reg = LinearRegression().fit(u_train, y_train)
```